# Общее кол-во показов AdMob банера уменьшилось

Tags: android, admob

**Вчера** общее число показов банера было, к примеру ***100***.

**Сегодня** общее кол-во стало на ***3*** меньше.

**Может ли быть такое ? Почему так выходит ?**

Comment: я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что вопрос следует адресовать в соответствующую техподдержку.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Возможно Вы указали в статистике период не за все время. Т.е. за прошлые 7 дней со вчера показов было 100, а за прошлые 7 дней с сгодня стало 97.

Проверьте за какое время показывает статистику

Comment: Да, точно, спасибо. Выбрал показывать за 7 дней..

Answer (score 2):

Может быть всякое.

Постоянные колебания, особенно такие незначительные (3%) - это нормально. Надо учитывать суточные/недельные/годовые циклы, праздники etc.

Вы можете сделать следующее:

1. Встроить к-л аналитику и сравнить помимо показов баннеров кол-во активных пользователей в день, длинну их сессий и их количество. Меньше пользуются приложением - меньше показов.
2. Увеличить частоту показа баннеров. Тогда при том же кол-ве и активности юзеров вы получите больше показов. Что не означает больший доход.